# VB.Net Application Download did not succeed

Tags: vb.net, deployment

I've encountered an error upon deploying a project for a few times. on my 18th revision of the project I noticed that it is not installing automatically after I opened my application. I tried to manually install it by running my system.application file but unfortunately I'm receiving a "Application Download did not succeed".

I've searched the web and did try some of the solution for this problem but none of them worked. I'm using VS2015 in coding this.

[image: Cannot Start Application]

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.17134.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.7.3416.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_B
    dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/KidsMonitoringSystem/Application%20Files/Kids%20Monitoring%20System_1_0_0_20/Kids%20Monitoring%20System.application
    Deployment Provider url     : file://users/Team%20Guilas/Desktop/Kids/Kids%20Monitoring%20System.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\KidsMonitoringSystem\Application Files\Kids Monitoring System_1_0_0_20\Kids Monitoring System.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file://users/Team Guilas/Desktop/Kids/Kids Monitoring System.application did not succeed.
        + The network path was not found.

        + The network path was not found.

        + The network path was not found.


COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/23/2019 12:50:20 AM] : Activation of C:\KidsMonitoringSystem\Application Files\Kids Monitoring System_1_0_0_20\Kids Monitoring System.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/23/2019 12:50:23 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file://users/Team Guilas/Desktop/Kids/Kids Monitoring System.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The network path was not found.

        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The network path was not found.

        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.IOException
        - The network path was not found.

        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer appears to be in the logged info you posted: your application is hosted on/published to a network location (smb file share?) and it has gone away:

> - Downloading file://users/Team Guilas/Desktop/Kids/Kids Monitoring System.application did not succeed.
> - The network path was not found.

Check your network connection, server availability, drive mappings etc and try again?